# how to make a thread of never stop, and write something to database every 10 second

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, multithreading

i using gae and django

this is my code:

```
class LogText(db.Model):
    content = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)


class MyThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,threadname):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, name=threadname)
    def run(self,request):
        log=LogText()
        log.content=request.POST.get('content',None)
        log.put()

def Log(request):
    thr = MyThread('haha')
    thr.run(request)

    return HttpResponse('')
```

Comment: To do this not on App Engine, try this link! www.google.com/search?q=python+thread

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to do in GAE since all requests (including cron job) have [30 seconds deadline](http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2009/02/skys-almost-limit-high-cpu-is-no-more.html).

Comment: how to realize this not on gae .

Comment: It's also impossible because you cannot start new threads on App Engine.